# Unity iAd Framework rejection by Apple

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, iad, appstore-approval

We got this error from Apple, they rejected our app because of this problem:

> PLA 3.3.12
>
> We found your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement states:
>
> "You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have contracted to serve advertising) may us the Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine, correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly, the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the reset Advertising Identifier."
>
> Please remove the iOS Advertising Identifier from your app or add ad functionality to your app.

We are not using iAd anywhere in the game, also by default only the iAd framework is added. How to remove iAd framework?

Comment: Do you use RevMob, ChartBoost or any other ad service provider? Or maybe some game analytics tool?

Comment: No we are not using any ad service, iAd is added by default in our Xcode file.

Comment: Whenever we try to remove iAd library , Mac o linking error comes, please provide sure solution to problem

Comment: If you're getting a linking error after removing iAd.framework, that means you're using code from that library. Why do you have it included in the first place?

Comment: I got the same rejection, but I've never added iAd and AdSupport framework into the project!

Comment: i'm thinking to remove all analytics libraries, GA and Flurry, from the project and upload the binary again.

Comment: I got rejected as well and it looks like Flurry: find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep advertisingIdentifier
Binary file ./Splickit/Pods/FlurrySDK/Flurry/libFlurry_4.3.0.a matches

Comment: There is an official statement from Unity in their blog, s. [Overcoming issues with iOS App Store submissions](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/02/11/overcoming-issues-with-ios-app-store-submissions/)

Answer (score 0):

Just select it from `Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries` and remove it.

[image]

Comment: `Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)`

Comment: Will this solve this problem, can we build archive after this and upload.  Also tell me why this problem came.

Comment: After we remove iAd library it gives MAC O LINKING Error, please tell how to solve this problem

Comment: Please tell exact solution in relation to IAd problem, it's urgent.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the iAd.framework as Jacky Boy mentioned, as well as iAd.mm and iAd_Scripting.mm (both found under Build Phases -> Compile Sources), you should be able to build.

Answer (score 0):

Unity just post a quick fix for this issue.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/226187-iOS-Advertising-Identifier-rejection-FAQ

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  Can you summarize the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Apple is not approving the apps which access the Advertising identifier, if it does not have any adds in it.

You not just need to remove the iAd framework but also need to remove the code which use it to resolve linking errors :)

The unity by default generate the code which access the advertising identifier even if we dont use any ads. So you cant fix it from unity . You need to change the code in your Xcode project which is generated by Xcode.

You can follow the [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/226187-iOS-Advertising-Identifier-rejection-FAQ) which have the guidlines to remove the code which access Advertising identifier and manually remove the iAd framework form Xcode.